# Number of possible combinations in matrix

Tags: matrix, combinations

My coworker gave me a challenging question that I believe is NP but he won't take that as an answer.

Given a matrix determine how many non repeating numbers/letter combinations there are by picking only one number per column. It isn't acceptable to brute force (try all possible combinations) for this. He wants a formula to solve this problem.

**For example he gave me this matrix**

1 2 2 3
2 3 3 4
3 4 4 5
4 5 5 6

**Some example results would be**

1) 1 2 3 4
2) 1 2 3 5
3) 1 2 3 6
4) 1 3 2 4
5) 1 3 2 5
6) etc...

I wrote a java program which basically consisted of 4 for loops to go through all possible combinations (4x4x4x4=256 combos) to get I believe the answer was 36 possible combos. But to him this in unacceptable. And for the solution it can't be independent to one matrix alone it has to work for all n x n matrices.

Been racking my brain on this and I believe the problem is np(hard/complete) because it can be solved in polynomial time but there is no general algorithm you can do...you have to brute force it.

Any help/pointers/places of reference would be greatly appreciated...